# How do I chain multiple selectors with filters in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to select multiple elements which do not have the attribute 'disabled' but I'm not sure if there's an easier way to type this:

```
$('input:not(:disabled), select:not(:disabled), textarea:not(:disabled)')
```

It seems a little wasteful to be typing multiple 'not(:disabled)'.

Answer (score 4):

This should work:

```
$('input, select, textarea').filter(':enabled');
```

Or if you want to get really short:

```
$(':input:enabled')
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the [:input](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/) selector along with the [.not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/) method

```
$(':input').not(':disabled')
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [`.not()` method](http://api.jquery.com/not/):

```
$('input, select, textarea').not(':disabled')
```

Which can be further simplified to:

```
$(':input').not(':disabled')
```

(Note that the [':input'](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/) selector selects button elements in addition to input, select and textarea elements.)